Failed to use GNU MIPS builtin functions of vector (SIMD)
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24) for a MIPS CPU. Now I want to test GNU builtin functions for MIPS SIMD listed in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-SIMD-Architecture-Built-in-Functions.html
I tested v4f32 __builtin_msa_fsqrt_w (v4f32); as follows.
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <msa.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ALIGN16 __attribute__((aligned(16)))
ALIGN16 uint32_t a[] = {64, 128, 256, 512};
ALIGN16 uint32_t r[] = {64, 128, 256, 512};
ALIGN16 uint32_t sr[] = {64, 128, 256, 512};

static int verification_test(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    v4i32 va, fr;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        sr[i] = sqrt(a[i]);
    }
    // Get SQRT with MSA builtin functions
    va = __builtin_msa_ld_w(a, 0);
    fr = (v4i32)__builtin_msa_fsqrt_w((v4f32)va);
    __builtin_msa_st_w(fr, r, 0); // Save result in fr to array of r.

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d: %f\n", i, (double)sr[i]);
        printf("%d: %f\n", i, (double)r[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    verification_test();
    return 0;
}

It cacluated sqrt of 4 numbers, but I found the results of builtin function are different from the results got from sqrt(), as follows.
0: 8.000000
0: 464848115.000000
1: 11.000000
1: 469762048.000000
2: 16.000000
2: 473236723.000000
3: 22.000000
3: 478150656.000000

So what is wrong with my codes, how to fix it?
Updated codes according to the answer
I changed the line to
fr = __builtin_msa_ftint_s_w(__builtin_msa_fsqrt_w(__builtin_msa_ffint_s_w(va)));

And I got the results as follows,
0: 8.000000
0: 8.000000
1: 11.000000
1: 11.000000
2: 16.000000
2: 16.000000
3: 22.000000
3: 23.000000 <<??

The last one is from MSA instruction, it is a little from the result of sqrt(), does it make sense?

This is almost certainly a representation issue that you could resolve by reading the documentation. Even though you are starting with integers and later later assigning your floating point results into the same uint32 space, the assembly routines are going to surprise you. Just a quick search reveals that the SIMD instruction is expecting floating point arguments, not integers. Wrong representation, wrong answer.

Also, instead of using the __builtin functions, you probably want to use the names from <msa.h>. For example, __msa_fsqrt_w instead of __builtin_msa_fsqrt_w.

I checked the msa.h in the toolchain, it has something like this #define __msa_fsqrt_w __builtin_msa_fsqrt_w, the __msa_fsqrt_w IS __builtin_msa_fsqrt_w in my system (GCC 7.2.0), so why should NOT use __builtin_msa_xxxx directly?

Educated guess here as I don't really know MIPS, but casting vector types between integer and float vector types needs to be done with the appropriate intrinsic. Try changing
(v4i32)__builtin_msa_fsqrt_w((v4f32)va) 

to
builtin_msa_ftint_u_w(__builtin_msa_fsqrt_w(__builtin_msa_ffint_u_w(va)))

You probably should check the documentation, if you can find some, on how it rounds to make sure it does what you expect.

Thanks for the answer, it is correct, I changed the codes as your suggested (a little different) to fr = __builtin_msa_ftint_s_w(__builtin_msa_fsqrt_w(__builtin_msa_ffint_s_w(va)));, I used the signed version of converting function. And I updated my question with results for your reference.

Your arrays are unsigned. That's why I used the 'u' versions. Maybe you should make them int32_t arrays instead then if you want signed.

Yep, I updated the code, and I think it worked. Thanks.
